# floating a div into the vertical space above - ie7 issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

You can see my issue here - http://jsfiddle.net/WuWPs/5/

Essentially I'm trying to have the lower three divs move up to below the first `div`.

I'm having no problems achieving this in a modern browser, but with ie7 it looks a mess.

I can't edit the html, I'd like to achieve the effect with only css changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by only changing the CSS, as requested.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/fVzDT/

In fact, your CSS hasn't actually been changed, I've simply added some magic at the end that [is applied in only IE7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_plus_hack):

```
/* ie7 hack */
*+html .block1, *+html .block2 {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works perfectly. I've not seen that hack before. Is there a similar one that works with ie6?

Comment: Ooops, just realised you left a link to various hacks in your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. In answer to your question: yes, [there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack). But, if you wanted to use that with what I already suggested, you'd need to duplicate the fix. So, I'm instead going to recommend the `*property: value` hack, which applies in IE7 and lower. **See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/fVzDT/2/

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the star plus hack - It's worth noting however that "The Microsoft Internet Explorer development team have asked that people use conditional comments http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment instead of hacks" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Criticism